# Converting Dictionary Data into a Data-Table

Tags: c#

I am facing a issue while converting a `Dictionary` into a `DataTable` in C#.

I have values in the `Dictionary` as `Dict<String , List<SomeModel>>`.

Eg Values -

```
(Key) -  , (Value) - 
                         Id    Pin    Desc   IsEligible-
                          1       A1    XYZ      0
                          2       A2    ABC      1
(Key) -  , (Value) -
                          Id    Pin    Desc   IsEligible-
                          1       A1    XYZ       1
                          2       A2    ABC       0
```

I want the result to be like -

```
  Id     Pin    Desc   IsEligible-   IsEligible-
   1       A1    XYZ       0                    1
   2       A2    ABC       1                    0
```

Code which populates the dictionary is -

```cs
resultSet.Add(eff, spResult.ToList());
```

this is my code . It adds a string as key which is `VA305` and as value it adds a list - which is of type `{ Id , Pin , Desc , IsEligible }`

Comment: I don't understand the Values in your first table. What exactly ist that `List`? Is it also a DataTable? Maybe it would be clearer if you show some code populating the Dictionary.

Comment: resultSet.Add(eff, spResult.ToList()); , this is my code . It adds a string as key which is VA305 and as value it adds a list - which is of type { Id , Pin , Desc , IsEligible } .

Comment: Done @klausGutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question completely, I assume you mean the following:

```
class Record
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Pin { get; set; }
 public string Desc { get; set; }
 public int IsEligible { get; set; }
}

var resultSet = new Dictionary<string, List<Record>>();

resultSet.Add("VA305", new List<Record> 
{
    new Record { Id = 1, Pin = "A1", Desc = "XYZ", IsEligible = 0 },
    new Record { Id = 2, Pin = "A2", Desc = "ABC", IsEligible = 1 },
});
resultSet.Add("VA310", new List<Record> 
{
    new Record { Id = 1, Pin = "A1", Desc = "XYZ", IsEligible = 1 },
    new Record { Id = 2, Pin = "A2", Desc = "ABC", IsEligible = 0 },
});
```

OK, let's first create the data table:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Pin"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc"));
foreach (var eff in resultSet.Keys)
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsEligible-" + eff));
```

You may add a more suitable data type if you want.

To populate it, I suggest to iterate over the dictionary

- first flatten the dictionary of lists so that each entry in the value produces one item, this can easily be done using Linq `SelectMany`
- then group by the Id, so we get one result item per Id (I assume that the Id is a unique identification and that Pin and Desc are the same for all items with the same Id).

This leads to:

```
foreach (var result in resultSet.SelectMany(r => r.Value, (r, v) => new { Eff = r.Key, Rec = v })
    .GroupBy(r => r.Rec.Id))
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = result.Key;
    row["Pin"] = result.First().Rec.Pin;
    row["Desc"] = result.First().Rec.Desc;
    foreach (var e in result)
    {
        row["IsEligible-" + e.Eff] = e.Rec.IsEligible;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I guess you understood the question correctly . Thank you so much for the solution , it really helped me in my task . Best wishes always .